# Energy in a point-plane symmetry problem

Tags: electrostatics

I was faced with a following problem:

A point charge $q$ is at a distance $l$ from an infinite conducting plane. Find the energy $W$ of interaction between this charge and the charges induced on the plane.

My thought process mostly revolved around localization of energy idea i.e. integrating the upper half of the space, but plane being infinite, as well as  having in mind that that would calculate the energy as a whole rather than an interaction.

The author's idea was to take $q$ to infinity and reason that the energy needed for that is equal to what we want (at this point the energy of the system is zero-$q$ is to far away to induce anything on the plate). However wouldn't energy of  plate itself and of the point-charge also take the hit?In which case  we only conserve $W_1+W_2+W_{12}$ rendering the idea useless?

Could someone point out if the idea is wrong or better yet I am?

Comment: is infinite conducting plane is grounded or not.

Comment: Well if it wasn't the potential of point-charge would be infinite so i think it's safe to assume it's grounded

Comment: if it's grounded then use "method of images"(it works very well in these kind of questions where one conductor is grounded) to solve the problem

Comment: that wasn't the point,i know what the field looks like in the whole upper plane it was the part why is it equivalent to take q to infinity

Answer (score 1):

The author is correct.

The interaction energy $W_0$ is the electrostatic potential energy of the system of charges. This is the work required to assemble a charge distribution, or the negative of that required to remove the charges until they are infinitely far apart where they no longer interact.

As the point charge $+q$ is withdrawn to an infinite distance from the plate, the -ve charges induced on the plate automatically disperse at the same time until they also are infinitely far apart. The movement of $+q$ causes the movement of the induced charges. So the work done $W_0$ to move $+q$ to infinity **includes** the potential energy $W_2$ which is released by the induced charges as they disperse.

This makes sense because, as you pointed out, the final configuration has no electrostatic potential energy.

If somehow the induced charge distribution had been frozen in place so that it did not move as $+q$ was withdrawn, then the work done $W_1$ to remove $+q$ would be higher than $W_0$, and there would be some electrostatic energy $W_2$ remaining in the charge distribution on the plate. That is : $$W_1=W_0+W_2$$

---

To calculate $W_0$ note that the induced charge distribution is equivalent to having a mirror-image of the charge $+q$ (see Method of Images).

Comment: Isn't there no work to assemble charges on the plate because it's an equipotential surface? I guess the problem doesn't specify that the plate is grounded.

Comment: @AaronStevens It is an infinite plate so it has infinite capacitance. I think this means that, by definition, it is grounded. Yes work is needed to assemble the induced charge distribution, but this is less than the work done on the point charge as it is brought close to the plate. Maybe I should add more about that.

Comment: If the plate is grounded then it is an equipotential. So there is no work needed to put the charges on it right?

Comment: If the plate is *conducting* then it is an equipotential. And it is an equipotential in the steady state if any excess charges are free to move. The sum of potentials due to the point charge and the induced charge distribution is zero. It would require work to assemble a distribution of -ve charges on the surface of a conductor.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Although I feel like I've seen examples like this where the author states no work is done on charges moving in l onto/off of the grounded conducting plate. Maybe I'll look back and see if my memory is incorrect.

Comment: i think i got it.As the plate is grounded it's potential energy is zero  (it'potential is zero) so all the energy is basically  the energy of interaction